# Override language settings

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code

I found out this particular file which can defined behavior of brackets, etc, in a specific language:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide

I would like to simply configure the addition of '$' before and after selected text in LaTeX documents, using for example 'alt+$' keybinding.

So far, it's not clear to me how to do that, even with the documentation pages I stumbled upon.
(https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributeslanguages for example).

I would think that you could simply do that in keybindings.json but it appears you can't (or I don't know how). 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly try this snippet:

```
{ 
  "key": "shift+alt+4",
  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "$${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$"
  },
   "editorLangId == latex"
},
```

For where to put that snippet see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets

It doesn't seem you can use `alt+$` directly but `shift+alt+4` is the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working. I've put the keybinding in keybindings.json
(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).
The only difference is that I'm using an AZERTY keyboard so I had to find which key was corresponding to '$' in the QWERTY layout (which is actually [BracketRight]).